# ASP.NET Core not logging entity framework queries

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to view SQL queries as they are logged in **Entity Framework Core** with a custom logger based on this page: http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/miscellaneous/logging.html

I see a lot of different log messages come through, but in the `CreateLogger` method, none of the strings passed in are a match for:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection
```

Has anyone successfully viewed Entity Framework **log** messages this way? I'm probably missing something simple.